# Dynamic Thyemeleaf field setter for fragment

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf, dropdown

I would like to create a fragment of a dropdown in this case, and would like to make it, so other custom objects can use it.
It should make more sense in code form:

**Dropdown Fragment:**

```
 <body th:fragment="dropdownSearch(field)">
   <div class="select is-normal">
     <input list="browsers" name="browser" th:field="*{field}">
     <datalist id="browsers">
       <option th:each="i : ${#numbers.sequence(0, __${valuesDataIndexSize - 1}__)}" 
        th:value="${i}" th:text="${i} + ' - Kommentar'"></option>
     </datalist>
   </div>
 </body>
```

**Fragment call example**

```
<div th:replace="fragments/dropdown.html :: dropdownSearch(field=*{projectOptions.zMatrixIndex})"></div>
```

The goal here is to make the `th:field` in the dropdown fragment dynamic so as seen in the fragment call example, it can be set to be custom, which in this case should be `projectOptions.zMatrixIndex`. So if I call the fragment and tell it, that field should be `test`, it should set the `th:field` in the fragment to `th:field="*{test}"`.

If I execute the code as it is now, I receive this error:

```
2022-09-22 15:57:39.818 ERROR 5516 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    
: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception 
[Request processing failed; nested exception is 
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 
'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor' (template: 
"fragments/dropdown.html" - line 8, col 41)] with root cause

org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'field' of bean class 
[com.tribus.tribusspring.entities.objects.project.main.ProjectData]: Bean property 'field' is 
not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the 
parameter type of the setter?
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass references to objects when using `th:field` instead, you have to pass the string name of the object and then use preprocessing.  Like this:

```
<div th:replace="fragments/dropdown.html :: dropdownSearch(field='projectOptions.zMatrixIndex')"></div>
```

and then

```
<input list="browsers" name="browser" th:field="*{__${field}__}">
```

(it's just how `th:field` works.)

Comment: Works for me, thank you. Even if it's a bit weird, the most important thing is that it works. Thanks!